# Execute the cURL request properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, curl

I have 2 entities provided below:

```
@Entity
public class Product {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String id;


    @Column
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Stock stock;
}


@Entity
public class Stock {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "stock_id")
    private String id;


    @Column
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    @Column
    private int quantity;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
}
```

My intention is to insert a product object in the database, so, if later I use the `GET` command, I will be able to retrieve a `JSON` similar to:

```
{
   "productId": “string", // id of the requested product, e.g. "vegetable-123" 
  "requestTimestamp": “dateTime", // datetime in UTC when requested the stock 

  "stock": {

     "id": "string", 
     "timestamp": 
     "dateTime" "quantity": "integer"

   } 
}
```

The API for the `POST` call is provided below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/products")
public class ProductAPI {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;

    @PostMapping(value = "/createProduct", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {

        service.save(product);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(product);
    }
}
```

The `cURL` request is provided,

`$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"id\" :`
`\"Product ID\",\"timestamp\" : \"2017-07-16 22:54:01.754\",\"id\":` `\"Stock ID\", \"timestamp\":\"2000-07-16 22:54:01.754\", \"quantity\":` `\"250\"}" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/createProduct`

The command is successful and delivers the output,

```
HTTP/1.1 201 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 15 Feb 2019 09:10:59 GMT

{"timestamp":"2000-07-16 22:54:01.754"}
```

However, the database entries are not correct,

[image]
[image]

How do I write the cURL POST request properly?

With the CURL command, I would like to populate the tables with the data and the response should return the same,

{
   "productId": "Product ID"
  "requestTimestamp": "2017-07-16 22:54:01.754"

"stock": {

```
 "id": "Stock ID", 
 "timestamp": "2000-07-16 22:54:01.754",
 "quantity": "250"
```

} 
}

Comment: Do not use entitioes in controller class. Learn about 3tier architecture

Comment: Better to use PostMan extension for chrome if user intention is testing only. if you want to achieve something else with this curl then i will suggest you to put the logs and see what body you are receiving at your servert and what is the status after you save the same into the database.

Comment: @Jens the entities are not in the controller/ API class

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal the cURL log is provided in the question. I get nothing in the `Stock` table and also the id field of the Product is not populated as intended.

Comment: @Arefe And which class is Product here:  `public ResponseEntity<Product> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {`?

Comment: I am not talking about the curl response i am asking you to fetch the request body at server side and print the same to check are you getting the proper data at you server. 201 as curl response didn't guarantee for the correct data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `Timestamp` field is not getting deserialised, you need to annotate `Timestamp` field with `@JsonFormat`, e.g.:

`@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")`

Below is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception { 
    String s = "{\"timestamp\":\"2000-07-16 22:54:01.754\"}";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Product product = objectMapper.readValue(s, Product.class);
    System.out.println(product.getTimestamp());
}

class Product {

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) is the documentation.

**update**

For the `Stock`, you need to pass it as a nested object to adhere to `Product` class structure, e.g.:

```
{
  "id": "Product ID",
  "timestamp": "2017-07-16 22:54:01.754",
  "stock" : {
  "id": "Stock ID",
  "timestamp": "2000-07-16 22:54:01.754",
  "quantity": "250"
  }
}
```

Your curl command will be:

```
$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"id\": \"Product ID\", 
\"timestamp\": \"2017-07-16 22:54:01.754\",  \"stock\" : {  \"id\": \"Stock ID\",  
\"timestamp\": \"2000-07-16 22:54:01.754\",  \"quantity\": \"250\"  }}" 
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/createProduct
```

Comment: Ok, this helps as I forget to add the annotation. So I added `    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")` to both of the tables. However, the questions still exists as I was not able to populate the other columns for the 2 tables. 

Please, have a look in the `cURL` queries as all the data needs to go inside the tables

Comment: I really expected this to work out as this seems very logical. However, I still don't have any entries in the database.

Comment: Can you check whether `Stock` object is getting populated in the controller? A sysout would do.

Comment: Now I get the `HTTP 400` error while executing the original query 

`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"id\" : \"Product ID\",\"timestamp\" : \"2017-07-16 22:54:01.754\",\"id\": \"Stock ID\", \"timestamp\":\"2000-07-16 22:54:01.754\", \"quantity\": \"250\"}" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/createProduct
HTTP/1.1 400 
Connection: close

{"timestamp":"2019-02-15T10:14:52.338+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed","path":"/api/v1/products/createProduct"}`

Comment: This is something I try to fix and get back to you afterward.